# Looping through multiple children in Firebase efficiently

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A part of my current Firebase Database looks like this:

[image]

I have only expanded one to show you the general structure of the JSON tree.

Within the "medium" child, I have 3 more sub-children of "a bit of both", "nature" and "urban". I already know how to extract the mappings under each trail (trailA, trailB, etc) in Android but I am not sure how to loop through the 3 sub-children mentioned above. Is it a for loop for DatabaseReferences or something else? My current code works but it is very inefficient, particularly when the data grows even bigger.

I am really new to Firebase and am only beginning to understand the structuring so please forgive me if this question is relatively basic. Any help (and further explanations) would be deeply appreciated.

My current code for extracting data from the sub-children is in the form of hard-code:

```
    List<DatabaseReference> dbList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference refB = firebaseDatabase.child("medium").child("a bit of both");
    DatabaseReference refC = firebaseDatabase.child("medium").child("nature");
    DatabaseReference refC = firebaseDatabase.child("medium").child("urban");
    dbList.add(refB);
    dbList.add(refC);
    for (DatabaseReference x : dbList) {
        x.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TrailInformation ti = ds.getValue(TrailInformation.class);
                    trailInformationCallback.onCallBack(ti);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you've shown?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code but I want to know if there is any way to do so efficiently.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do to improve the performance of a simple loop like that.  Generally speaking, it's said that it's not good to worry about performance until you actually observe a performance problems.

Comment: You can use Queries and [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) to process smaller sections of the list. `limitToFirst, limitToLast, startAt, endAt`